# $_POST[] to hold arrays ... help

Tags: php

I want to append using jquery some `<input>` fields to a form like this

```
<form>
<input>
<input>
<input>
</form>
```

and when this form is processed i want to add multiple rows in database. for every field i want to add a row in database like this

```
('1','field_name');
('2', 'field_name');
('3', 'field_name');
```

How to manipulate the `<input>` to be processed in a `$_POST['field'][0]` , `$_POST['field'][1]` .. and so on ?

what is necesarry for the `<input>` tag to have as name ? `<input name='field'>` or `<input name='field[]'>` or if there's any other solution ... i heed some help . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered it yourself in the question:

```
<input name="field[]" />
```

This behaviour is documented in the PHP manual in [PHP and HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

To do this with jquery you would do something like the following:

```
$('<input />', {
    "name": "field[]",
    "type": "text"
}).appendTo("body");
```

This is the way to [create new elements in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery#jQuery2) and add them to the body of the page.

To address concerns in your comments:

```
$('<input />', {
    "name": "field[]",
    "type": "text"
}).appendTo("#my-form-id");
```

Comment: thanks , but i didn't know that is possible .. i just assumed .. thanks a lot

Comment: what's with the `$('<input>')` ? Assume that i want to append it to the form like `$('#formname).append(...???...)` like that ... `.append('<input type=text name=field[]>')` ??? thank you

Comment: @pufos it is the correct way to create new elements in jQuery. It is far more useful than typing the HTML in straight as you can reuse object definitions etc.

Comment: Oh, i understand now ... i'm reading the article you gave. Thanks a lot for your answer ..

Answer (score 4):

The `name="field[]"` solution will give you the desired behaviour.
You can also define the order of the fields by

```
<input name="field[0]" />
<input name="field[1]" />
<input name="field[2]" />
```

But then make sure you don't have a double index.

Comment: tthe problem is that i append them using jquery and i don;t know how to add the extra `[0]`, `[1]` to the appended `<input>`

Comment: If you don't want to have a different order from the order in which you show the inputs it is not necessary to code the indices in, because then they will be in the right order anyway. And if the order does not matter to you at all you can leave them out anyway.